# Android MediaRecorder CaptureReate and VideoFrameRate have no effect

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I'm using the MediaRecorder to record the device's screen. I'd like to be able to control the frame rate of the video captured.

I've tried setting both the Capture Rate and the VideoFrameRate properties of the MediaRecorder, but they seem to have no effect:

```
this.mRecorder.setCaptureRate(this.fps);
this.mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(this.fps);
```

As per the documentation ([setCaptureRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setCaptureRate(double)), [setVideoFrameRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setVideoFrameRate(int))), I am calling `setCaptureRate` and `setVideoFrameRate` *after* setting the format and video source, and *before* calling `prepare`:

```
this.mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
this.mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
this.mRecorder.setVideoSource(2);
this.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(2);
this.mRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mFilePath);
this.mRecorder.setVideoSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
this.mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(2);
this.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(2);
this.mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(this.mBitRate);
this.mRecorder.setCaptureRate(this.fps);
this.mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(this.fps);
this.mRecorder.prepare();
```

I've checked, and `this.fps` is set to 5, so it is not like some other incorrect value... and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setCaptureRate(double)) says:

> The fps can go as low as desired

Does anyone know how to set the FPS?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue. I can't seem to change the frame rate of the video captured from recording the device's screen. I've tried Capture Rate and Video Frame Rate and neither of them have an effect.

Comment: @Nate Nope. Sorry.